# How can I rewrite this code that modifies multiple fields that are named sequentially?

Tags: apex, fields

I have multiple fields that are named sequentially, i.e. nv001_*c, nv002*_c, nv003_*c and so on till nv026*_c. Is there a way for me to streamline the code below?

I know apex is different than VBA and apex is strongly typed but I am sure I made it harder for myself than it needed to be.

I have enclosed a small example of the code below. I am setting the scale for the individual fields dependent upon another variable.

```
// Set the Scale

If(mm == true){
    sc = 2;
} else {
    sc = 4;
}

//Nominal Values

if(toolResults[0].NV001__c != null){
    toolResults[0].NV001__c = toolResults[0].NV001__c.SetScale(sc);
}
if(toolResults[0].NV002__c != null){
    toolResults[0].NV002__c = toolResults[0].NV002__c.SetScale(sc);
}
if(toolResults[0].NV003__c != null){
    toolResults[0].NV003__c = toolResults[0].NV003__c.SetScale(sc);
}
if(toolResults[0].NV004__c != null){
    toolResults[0].NV004__c = toolResults[0].NV004__c.SetScale(sc);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if (mm){, you don't need to check if (true == true).

Comment: Thanks @mast0r. I need to remember this one as well. Makes things simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All SObjects support map-like get and put methods (see [sObject Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/Chunk93021001.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject)) so the fields can be accessed using strings for the names:

```
SObject sob = toolResults[0];
for (Integer i = 1; i <= 26; i++) {
    String field = (i < 10 ? 'NV00' + i : 'NV0' + i) + '__c';
    if (sob.get(field) != null) {
        Decimal d = (Decimal) sob.get(feld);
        sob.put(field, d.setScale(sc));
    }
}
```

**PS** One version of the field names in an array (see comment discussion); with only 26 I would just type them in as below (mainly for the clarity it brings to the code) but you could create the array with a loop if you wanted to.

```
String[] fields = new String[] {
        'NV001__c',
        'NV002__c',
        'NV003__c',
        ...
        };
SObject sob = toolResults[0];
for (String field : fields) {
    Object o = sob.get(field);
    if (o != null) {
        sob.put(field, ((Decimal) o).setScale(sc));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach but it could perhaps be made more readable by moving the field names into a field array and iterating over that.

Comment: @PhilRymek Fair enough, particularly if the field names were used multiple times. Hopefully the get/put is the key take away here though.

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was a better way to do this. This makes perfect sense. Phil, what would the code look like if the field names were moved into an Array? Keith C, thanks for your information. I think the big takeaway is the get/put.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. I appreciate all of the advice from both of you.